# Definition of r-ply transitivity (permutation group)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, definition, symmetric-groups

> A group of permutations $\Gamma$ of a set $E$ is called *r-ply
>   transitive* if, for any two sequences
>   $(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_r),(b_1,\ldots,b_r)$ of $r$ distinct elements of
>   $E$, there exists a permutation $\sigma\in\Gamma$ such that
>   $\sigma(a_i)=b_i$ for $1\leq i\leq r$, **this property not holding for
>   at least one ordered pair of sequences of $r+1$ distinct elements of
>   $E$**.

Is the bolded part necessary? I have never seen a definition of multiple transitivity that includes it. Why add it?

Comment: It lets you focus on $r$.  It's easier than saying that $\Gamma$ is $r$-ply transitive but not $r+1$-ply transitive.

Comment: This is not standard, and I think in most applications, the "wrong" definition. Most of the time, when you want a $2$-transitive group, you don't care if it happens to be $3$-transitive. Same with a $1$-transitive group with respect to $2$-transitive. It's easier to specify this in the few cases where it matters.

Comment: I have no idea whether this is standard because, as far as I can recall, I have never come across the term "$r$-ply transitive" before. I have heard of $r$-transitive and $r$-fold transitive but not $r$-ply transitive. The standard definition of these terms definitely does not have the extra condition (so we get the lemma that says $(r+1)$-transtive implies $r$-transitive, but it has the extra condition that $|E| \ge r$, which you have left out.

Comment: So with your definition, the symmetric group $S_n$ is not $n$-ply transitive, and it is hard to believe  that was intended!