# Transitivity and primitivity

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Consider the following definition:

> A group of permutations $\Gamma$ of a set $E$ is called $r$*-ply
>   transitive* if, for any two sequences $(a_1,a_2,\ldots a_r),
> (b_1,b_2,\ldots,b_r)$ of $r$ distinct elements of $E$, there exists a
>   permutation $\sigma\in\Gamma$ such that $\sigma(a_i)=b_i$ for $1\leq
>  i\leq r$, this property not holding for at least one ordered pair of
>   sequences of $r+1$ distinct elements of $E$.
>
> 1. Show that an $r$-ply transitive group is primitive for $r>1$.

Does this imply that $2\leq r\leq |E|-1$?

I can prove (1) for $r=2$. Assuming it for some $r\ge 2$, I have to prove it for $r+1$. However, I am not sure how to exhibit two sequences $(x_1,x_2,\ldots x_r),(y_1,y_2,\ldots,y_r)$ of $r$ distinct elements of $E$ such that
$$(\forall\sigma)[\sigma\in \Gamma\Rightarrow(y_1,y_2,\ldots,y_r)\ne(\sigma(x_1),\sigma(x_2),\ldots \sigma(x_r))].$$
I know that by assumption there exist two sequences $(a_1,a_2,\ldots a_{r+1}),
(b_1,b_2,\ldots,b_{r+1})$ of distinct $r+1$ elements of $E$ for which
$$(\forall\sigma)[\sigma\in \Gamma\Rightarrow(b_1,b_2,\ldots,b_{r+1})\ne(\sigma(a_1),\sigma(a_2),\ldots \sigma(a_{r+1}))].$$
holds. I just don't know how to extract the required $r$-tuples from these $(r+1)$-tuples.

Basically I want show that $(r+1)$-ply transitivity implies $r$-ply transitivity, from which I can conclude primitivity.

Comment: Are you the same user who posted [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3569623/definition-of-r-ply-transitivity-permutation-group) on the definition of $r$-ply transtivity? If so, please don't create  new accounts; use the same account for all your questions and answers, and ask the moderators to merge the two.

Answer (score 1):

If $G$ is $r$-ply transitive, then $r\lt |E|$. This follows from the last clause of the definition. Note that if $k\gt |E|$, then the condition "for every pair of $k$-tuples $(a_1,\ldots,a_k)$, $(b_1,\ldots,b_k)$ of elements of $E$, $a_i$ pairwise distinct, $b_j$ pairwise distinct, there exists $\sigma\in G$ such that $\sigma(a_i)=b_i$ for $i=1,\ldots,k$" holds by vacuity (there are *no* such tuples, so for every pair of such tuples $\sigma$ exists). Thus, $G$ cannot be $r$-ply transitive with $r\geq|E|$.

Likewise, that final clause in the definition means that you *cannot* prove what you say you want to prove (that $(r+1)$-ply transitivity implies $r$-ply transitivity): if $G$ is $(r+1)$-ply transitive, then there do not exist two sequences of $r+1$ distinct elements of $E$, $(a_1,\ldots,a_{r+1})$ and $(b_1,\ldots,b_{r+1})$ for which there is *no* $\sigma\in G$ with $\sigma(a_i)=b_i$; the fact that $G$ **is** $(r+1)$-ply transitive tells you that such a $\sigma$ *always* exists, so $G$ fails the final clause of the definition for $r$-ply transitivity; thus, it cannot be $r$-ply transitive.

To prove that the action is primitive if $r\gt 2$, assume to the contrary that there is a nontrivial block $B$; then $B$ contains at least two elements $x_1\neq x_2$, but fails to contain at least one element $b$. Since $G$ is $r$-ply transitive, $E$ contains at least $r+1$ elements, and so we can find elements $a_3,\ldots,a_r$, pairwise distinct and distinct from $x_1$, $x_2$, and $b$. Now consider the tuples $(x_1,x_2,a_3,\ldots,a_r)$ and $(x_1,b,a_3,\ldots,a_r)$ and use $r$-ply transitivity to show that there is an element $\sigma\in G$ such that $\sigma(B)\neq B$ but $\sigma(B)\cap B\neq\varnothing$.